# dataframe query in R nodes graph

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have the data frame

```
df<-data.frame(source=c("a","a","a",'z1','b'),target=c("b","c","d",'a','e'),wsource=c('w1','w2','w1','w2','w1'),wtarget=c('w1','w1','w1','w1','w2'))

source target wsource wtarget
 a      b       w1       w1
 a      c       w1       w1
 a      d       w1       w1
z1      a       w2       w1
 b      e       w1       w2
```

which represents a graph (`source` and `target` are node ids, and `wsource` and `wtarget` are labels). I want to get for each distinct node the number of times it is associated with wtarget if the node is in the source column plus the number of times it is associated with wsource if the node is n the target column.

The data frame I'm looking for is:

```
node w1 w2
  a  3  1
  b  1  1
  c  1  0
  d  1  0
  e  1  0
 z1  1  0
```

Note for instance that node `a` gets its 3 in column `w1` from the three times it appears as source (look at its corresponding wtarget), and gets its 1 in column `w2` from the fourth row where it appears as target (look at its corresponding wsource).

I tried to first sort the column but in my application, the node ids are long integers. Even if you sort them you cannot guarantee that a node is going to appear in only one column (source or target).

I'd like to know a way to handle this query.

Comment: I admit I'm lost here. I don't understand what it is you are tabulating.

Comment: I know, it's hard to explain. For each distinct node, I need to count the number of ``w1``, ``w2`` it has assigned in ``wsource`` and ``wtarget``. But note that a node can happen in both columns source and target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlist and table:

Align the `source--target` with the `wtarget--wsource` so all the nodes are brought together in one column, and all the labels in another column, and use `table` to generate the result:

```
table(
  unlist(df[c("source","target")]),
  unlist(df[c("wtarget","wsource")])
)

#       w1 w2
#    a   3  1
#    b   1  1
#    c   0  1
#    d   1  0
#    e   1  0
#    z1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the full list of nodes:

```
sources<-unique(df$source)
targets<-unique(df$target)
st<-unique(c(sources,targets))
```

Set up variables for the `for` loop:

```
node<-NULL
w1<-NULL
w2<-NULL
```

Create the columns:

```
for(i in 1:length(st)) {
  node[i]<-st[i]
  w1[i]<-sum(df$wtarget[df$source==st[i]]==1, df$wsource[df$target==st[i]]==1)
  w2[i]<-sum(df$wtarget[df$source==st[i]]==2, df$wsource[df$target==st[i]]==2)
}
```

combine everything together with cbind:

```
cbind(node,w1,w2)
```

result:

```
      node w1  w2 
 [1,] "a"  "3" "1"
 [2,] "z1" "1" "0"
 [3,] "b"  "1" "1"
 [4,] "c"  "0" "1"
 [5,] "d"  "1" "0"
 [6,] "e"  "1" "0"
```

If you want this ordered you can add the following line:

```
nodelist<-cbind(node,w1,w2)
nodelist<-nodelist[order(nodelist[,1]),]

     node w1  w2 
[1,] "a"  "3" "1"
[2,] "b"  "1" "1"
[3,] "c"  "0" "1"
[4,] "d"  "1" "0"
[5,] "e"  "1" "0"
[6,] "z1" "1" "0"
```

UPDATE: Here's a generalized version for multiple w's:

```
sources<-unique(df$source)
targets<-unique(df$target)
st<-unique(c(sources,targets))
node<-NULL
nodes<-NULL
w<-NULL
for(t in 1:max(c(df$wsource,df$wtarget))) {
  for(i in 1:length(st)) {
    node[i]<-st[i]
    w[i]<-sum(df$wtarget[df$source==st[i]]==t,     df$wsource[df$target==st[i]]==t)
  }
  nodes<-cbind(nodes,w)
}
nodelist<-data.frame(cbind(node,nodes))
nodelist<-nodelist[order(nodelist[,1]),]
```

You'll need a tiny bit more work to fix the column names, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: good one! what happens if we have dozens of ``wi``? (forgot to mention this in the question) I wanted to avoid the for loop.

Comment: added a generalized version

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(source=c("a","a","a",'z1','b'),target=c("b","c","d",'a','e'),wsource=c(1,2,1,2,1),wtarget=c(1,1,1,1,2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- rbind(as.matrix(df[, c(1, 4)]), as.matrix(df[, c(2, 3)]))
df <- df %>% data.frame %>% group_by(source, wtarget) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>%
  spread(wtarget, n) %>% mutate(`1` = ifelse(is.na(`1`), 0, `1`), `2` = ifelse(is.na(`2`), 0, `2`))
apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups: source [6]
  source   `1`   `2`
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a       3.00  1.00
2 b       1.00  1.00
3 c       0     1.00
4 d       1.00  0   
5 e       1.00  0   
6 z1      1.00  0
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: how would your code change if we have not only two ``wi``s but dozens ?

Comment: I made one more minor edit to be more robust.  The code should be able to handle many `wi`s.